# Entry Point Not Found

Tags: windows-xp, installation, compact-disc, dell-inspiron, windows-error-reporting

[image]I tried installing a linksys Wirless Adapter onto a Dell Inspiron 4100 laptop, and get a error that says:

Example:

"Setup.exe - Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point DecodePointer could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll."

I have a feeling I might have not installed everything on the computer, maybe a service pack isn't updated is what I've found online. I'm not sure if the cd I have should do the trick, or if I need to download something online? I have all the CD's to install onto the computer if somebody can give me the rundown, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the driver your trying to install is for Windows XP? I've seen this happen when you attempt to install Windows 7 drivers on an XP machine.

Comment: Nope it's windows XP for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your Windows XP version is *fully patched and updated to Windows XP Service Pack 3*.

This:

> could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

Means that the application is not written for whatever version of the operating system (`KERNEL32.DLL` is a core Windows file) that you have installed. If you know you have the correct major version (i.e., XP, Vista, 7, 8), then this usually indicates that software requires an older or newer minor version (service pack). Tentative research on `DecodePointer` suggests you need a newer version.

Comment: Is that on one of my CD's I have? Or would I install that online?

Comment: If it didn't get installed with the OS, then you'll download it from Microsoft's website: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24

Comment: I faced similar strange errors once while attempting to install Office 2010 on a fresh copy of XP. After I finished waiting a few hours for the OS to be up to date via Win Update the install went off without a hitch.

Comment: @Seth Urquhart this function was added with the Sp2. So install the Sp3 and it will work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I did it worked!

Comment: @SethUrquhart You should click the empty checkbox next to the answer to "Accept" it then, so that other users can easily see that it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem also. I had a few games for win7 and transferred therm to winxp and most games said decodepointerer error. It seems reinstalling a few games did the trick, but all other games still had the error. It seems installed service pack 1,2, or 3 onto XP will fix it, although you may then get a different .dll error. Just update your whole OS to Windows Service Pack 3, as games that say "windows xp compatible", really want to say "Windows XP SP3 comaptible." A few new games don't even run with Windows XP anymore. It may be worth it to update to Windows Vista, as it isn't so much of a performance jump in terms of CPU and RAM as Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `Sfc /scannow` in prompt command, will inspect all of the important Windows files on your computer, including Windows DLL files. If System File Checker finds an issue with any of these protected files, it will replace it.

Comment: I've already done that and restarted my computer, it didn't change anything.